# Angular's compile doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, compilation

I've faced a really strange situation with $compile service. I'm trying to compile a template which I get from back-end using my controller.

Here is JS:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('AC', ['HtmlProcessor', function Actrl(HtmlProcessor) {
  this.abc = 'Hello!';
  this.do = function () {
    alert(HtmlProcessor.getHTML(this));
  };
}]);

angular.module('app').service('HtmlProcessor', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  this.getHTML = function (scope) {
    return $compile('<p>{{ abc }}</p>')(scope).html();
  };
}]);
```

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AC as ac">
  <button ng-click="ac.do()">Compile!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the problem is that when I call `ac.do()` I get an error (in angular's textInterpolateFn) and template is not compiled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function signature you expecting a [Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) instance:

```
/*
 * @param {Scope} scope
 */
this.getHTML = function (scope) {
```

Also, [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) returns a composite linking function that expects a **Scope**, which in turn is passed on to all directives controllers and linking functions which also expects a **Scope** type.

You passed a wrong type to the function:

```
alert(HtmlProcessor.getHTML(this));
```

In your case the **this** keyword lost it's context but even if you saved it like so:

```
this.do = angular.bind(this, function () {
  alert(HtmlProcessor.getHTML(this));
});
```

It wouldn't work, because a controller's context (**this**) is not of a **Scope** type, its just a generic Function object of type **Constructor**

For example in your code it would fail in this directive:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I got it later while struggling with my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I've found the root of the problem. After linking I had to run digest cycle. Thus, I am creating a new scope, populate it with data, pass it to linking function and trigger digest:

```
this.getHTML = function (scope) {

  var newScope = $rootScope.$new();
  angular.extend(newScope, scope);

  var compiled = $compile('<p>{{ abc }}</p>')(newScope);

  newScope.$apply();

  return compiled.html();
};
```

Comment: This was very helpful! The need of a digest cycle seems to be a bug in Angular, seeing how things are rather inconsistent: When inheriting from some scopes (instead of `$rootScope`, I'd use some `$scope`) it works, when inheriting from others it won't; very random (but probably related to the parent scope's current digest state). Calling `$digest` fixes everything. However!!! you cannot call `$apply` or `$digest` delayed; meaning you must run the entire compilation process (when using a `$new` scope) outside of a digest cycle (e.g. by using `$timeout` or `setTimeout`).